How to convert a jpeg logo to a vector for engraving purposes in inkscape
Hi I need to convert a logo from jpeg to vector for engraving purposes.  It needs to be a black  line drawing with no fill or pixels. I have downloaded inkscape but am struggling. It's for a remembrance plaque for a charity I run.
Any help to do this would be much appreciated!


There is a Bitmap Trace option in Inkscape: https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html

However the "correct" way to do it is to ask for an original that is already in vector. Your client should have it, probably in PDF format.

If it is a well-known brand there is a chance you can find it online. It would be best if you compared it before using it to see if the version online is accurate.

If it is a small client and does not have it on vector, they should hire a designer to retrace it manually. It now should be saved as an original.


They probably need to find suitable fonts and combine shapes and curves to redraw it.

If you are the client... see point 4.


The auto-trace feature on any program gives you a rough version that might not work. It might have a lot of details lost and deformed.
It is mainly used for stylistic projects, for example converting a photo into a geometrical look, never to trace a logotype.

Looks like the OP is the client, since they said it's for "a charity I run". They are clearly trying to do this themselves. Obviously, if a graphic designer made the logo, they might have the original vector file.

I added the case 5. n_n

There's no simple answer here. It would have been better if you had shared the logo image so we could see what it looks like. There are several issues with automated bitmap tracing. Sometimes it can work well, but sometimes the results can be so bad, they're practically useless.
In Inkscape, you can access the automated bitmap tracing functionality from the main menu, under Path > Trace Bitmap. There are tutorials on youtube which show how to use it. Make sure to choose a recent tutorial as this functionality has changed somewhat over the years.
Some things to consider
Automated Bitmap Tracing in Inkscape is highly dependent on image quality. The larger the bitmap image (the higher the resolution), the better the result will be.
The type of image itself may or may not be suitable for automatic bitmap tracing. For example, an image with gradients or blurs or multiple colours might not trace so well.
If the image is all black (or one colour), and the image is high resolution, your chances of success will increase.
If the image has areas of small or fine details these may be lost during the trace process. Simpler less complex images work best.
If a logo also has text, this adds extra complexity, and it might be worthwhile simply deleting the traced text and retyping it instead.
If the image is not good enough, the next option would be to manually trace (redraw) the bitmap image by using the pen tool.
If a graphic designer made the logo for you, there's a possibility they may have the original vector file, and you could simply ask them to send you a PDF (containing the vectors) which you could then import into Inkscape. Obviously, if this is the case, you can avoid all of the above.

It's a bit of a cheat/work-around, but the bitmap trace in LightBurn (laser cutting software) is a great program with which to accomplish your goal. The "cheat" aspect is that they provide a 30 day free trial, with full capabilities. Plenty of YouTube videos on the internet with more than a few aimed at the bitmap trace option.
